# Custom MVC 5 controller routing with input as model

Tags: routes, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller whose input is a model:

```
public ActionResult arama(AramaSayfa gelen)
{
    ......
}
```

My model is as follows:

```
public class AramaSayfa
{
    public string ne { get; set;}
    public int neKadar { get; set;}
    public datetime neZaman { get; set;}
}
```

The controller is called from a `beginform` in Razor.  When the submit button clicked, the link generated is:

```
  /h/arama?ne=asd&neKadar=234&neZaman=01-03-2014
```

I want to make it more SEO friendly and shorten this to:

`/arama/asd/234/asd-234-den-basliyan-fiyatlarla` -

The last part is just generated for sea reasons and wont affect the controller. How can I do this?

Comment: Implement an override in RouteConfig.cs

Comment: I tried but dont know how to give the model properties to route